# Prove this is a subgroup: Subset of $S(A)$ consisting of all the permutations $f(a) = a$

Tags: group-theory, permutations

Let $A$ be a set and $a \in A$. Let $G$ be the subset of $S(A)$ consisting of all the permutations $f$ of $A$ such that $f(a)=a$. Prove that $G$ is a subgroup of $S(A)$.

I really have no clue how to go about this other than needed to prove that $G$ is closed and contains it's inverse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The identity permutation fixes $a$, and so is in $G$. If $f,g$ fix $a$, then $(fg)(a)=f(g(a))=f(a)=a$, so $fg$ fixes $a$. Therefore, $G$ is closed under multiplication. If $f$ fixes $a$, then $a=f^{-1}(f(a))=f^{-1}(a)$, so $f^{-1}$ fixes $a$. Therefore, $G$ is closed under inversion.

Answer (score 0):

You may check the subgroup criterion — $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ **iff** $H$ is non-empty and for every $x, y \in H, \, xy^{-1}\in H$.